# fatfs: after f_stat the directory is created

Tags: c, embedded, embedded-linux, fat

The [Fatfs](http://elm-chan.org/fsw/ff/00index_e.html) is R0.08b. What I do is detecting whether a dir is existed. I use `f_stat` to check the status.

The problem is: if I clear the `/root` directory and then call :

```
sprintf(p, "%s", "0:/testdir");
frs = f_stat(p, NULL);
```

the `frs` will return `FR_OK`. And then I can find there is a `/testdir` created. However, the `/testdir` can't be open until I re-mount the SD card.

Any idea?

Comment: ELM Fatfs has an active [user forum](http://elm-chan.org/fsw/ff/bd/), you should ask there perhaps.  Note also that 0.08b is not the latest code so you might check for updates too.

Comment: question about fatfs has its user forum.